why is the content in navigation_fragment_view invisible
im very new to android development and i am trying to implement a hamburger button drawer with a few different tabs. here is my code for the different components. I have tried everythignn i could think of and have been banging my head on the computer for about 3 hours trying to figure this out.
main activity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    NavController navController;
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        //get the drawer, navigation vew and navcontroller
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navHostFragment =(NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_fragment_view);
        assert navHostFragment != null;
        navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
        assert navController != null;

        //set up the action bar
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();
        //NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        //set up the navigation view
        //NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if(id == R.id.Home_navigation_button){
                navController.navigate(R.id.Home);
            }
            else if (id == R.id.ReservationPage_navigation_button){
                navController.navigate(R.id.ReservationPage);
            }
            drawerLayout.close();
            return true;
        });
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
            String label = destination.getLabel().toString();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(label);
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



activity main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_fragment_view"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

header.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

home.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Home"
    android:background="@color/black"



    >


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Home_to_ReservationPage_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/ReservationPage_label"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Home" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>

home.java
package com.example.parkstreet.cms.homeapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.example.parkstreet.cms.homeapp.databinding.HomeBinding;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    private HomeBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    )
    {

        binding = HomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.HomeToReservationPageButton.setOnClickListener(v ->
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.ReservationPage)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}

the drawer seems to work as the name of the page shows on the top of the toolbar but the actual page is just plain white.
i have tried everything from changing the layout width of every layer of the tree from the button on the home page to the constrained layout box. i dont see why its always invisible regardless if on the reservation page or home page.
